# Photoshop Printing and scaling

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, graphic-styles

I am creating a poster 60cm height and 90cm for printing.

I tried using Photoshop and set the document for 60x90cm and worked the designs. And after when I save the document in PDF for print, the output is very large 250mb.

I am worried whether this works for my client, He says the document is very large.

Comment: It is not terribly big in my oppinion.

Answer (score 2):

Files at print resolution, for commercial printing, are **always** larger in terms of kb/mb. File size should *never* be a concern for printing, quality should be the greatest concern.

The notion that one has to watch file sizes is entirely related to web/screen production and is completely irrelevant for print production. Design your piece at the correct resolution, size, with proper bleeds, etc and completely ignore any file sizes, they don't matter.

The *only* time file size is even a question is when one needs to transfer files for production. Then, you may need to look at more robust transfer methods than simply email, such as FTP, or Dropbox, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving the document as a Photoshop PDF with the "Preserve Photoshop Editing Capabilities" option checked, it will also include the Photoshop document.

If that document has multiple layers it could be what is making the file size so large. So you might be able to get the file size down by simply exporting without that option checked.

[image]

Here's an extreme example: for a piece of work I was actually commissioned to produce for a client.

I had a PSD document which was 299MB - with many layers.  When I saved as Photoshop PDF with the "preserve photoshop editing capabilities" checked, the PDF file size was 306MB.  When I switched that option off, the PDF was only 17.4MB

Of course, this will depend on the kind of image you have, but try that solution, and see if it changes the PDF size for you.